# unable to find multiple line by regex

Tags: python, regex

I am unable to find matches on multiple line in groups by using regex

```
import re

text = "import alkfa dfa aldkf \n import my name is xyz \n i am 
working incoverfox"

m = re.findall(r'^(import .+?$)', text, re.MULTILINE)
print(m)
```

expected result: ['import alkfa dfa aldkf ', import my name is xyz]
actual result: ['import alkfa dfa aldkf ']

Comment: remove '^'  from re.findall line

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = "a import alkfa dfa aldkf \n import my name is xyz \n i am working incoverfox"
re.findall(r'(import .+)', text)
```

`r'(import .+)'` will find the string begin with `import` end with any character except `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also without multiline flag

```
re.findall(r'(import .+)\n*', text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space after the new line character \n and you should be good to go.